# How can I give a CSS grid row a height so that the height of one of the divs in the row will be equal to the height of the text inside of it?

Tags: css

I have a 3-column, 1-row grid.  The left and right columns have their `height` set to 600px.  The middle column has some text inside of it (and the text is less than 600px tall).

I want the middle column to be as tall as the text inside of it, but `column-template-rows: auto` makes its height the same as the two divs around it, which is 600px.

Any help will be appreciated.  Thank you.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id='grid-container'>
    <div class='side-grid-item'>First column</div>
    <div id='grid-item'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    <div class='side-grid-item'>Third column</div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 384px 512px 384px;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto; /* The second auto is where my problem is*/
}

.side-grid-item {
    height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: what if you post code instead of describing it?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried, but it didn't turn out well.  I'll try again.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Alright, done.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to consider [alignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items):

```css
#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 384px 512px 384px;
  align-items:start; /*added this*/
}
#grid-container > div {
  background:pink;
}
.side-grid-item {
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div id='grid-container'>
  <div class='side-grid-item'>First column</div>
  <div id='grid-item'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div class='side-grid-item'>Third column</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  What if I have multiple divs in the middle column?

Comment: @MehranJ how with multiple divs ?